# How do you animate a UIWebView in swift?

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I'm looking to do this in Swift, but I don't know how to write this in swift:

```
webView.frame = CGRectMake(someX, self.view.frame.size.height, someWidth,    someHeight);
webView.hidden = NO;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
webView.frame = CGRectMake(someX, self.view.frame.size.height/2, someWidth, someHeight);
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the swift code for the above Obj-C code:

```
webView.frame = CGRectMake(someX, someY, someWidth, someHeight)
webView.hidden = false
UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(animationCurve), animations: { () -> Void in
   webView.frame = CGRectMake(someX, someOtherY, someWidth, someHeight)
}, completion: {(finished) -> () in
   // you can leave this empty
})
```

That should do it in Swift.